# Android TabLayout fixed mode but different weights

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-tablayout, androiddesignsupport

I have 4 tabs, one of them has the double size of others, so the weights will be: 20% 40% 20% 20%

But when I use TabLayout (from the android design support library) setting the mode to **fixed**, then I'm forced to have the same weight for all! here's the part of their source code that applies the width:

```
private void updateTabViewLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp) {
    if (mMode == MODE_FIXED && mTabGravity == GRAVITY_FILL) {
        lp.width = 0;
        lp.weight = 1;
    } else {
        lp.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.weight = 0;
    }
}
```

But I need different weights, and to fit the screen width. Any way to apply my own weights?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    //SlidingTabStrip in TabLayout
    ViewGroup slidingTabStrip = (ViewGroup)mTablayout.getChildAt(0);
    //second tab in SlidingTabStrip
    View tab1 = slidingTabStrip.getChildAt(1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tab1.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.weight = 2;
    tab1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```